# DatagridColumn sort event?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, datagrid

Is there an event that gets fired when one clicks the ColumnHeader of a Datagrid to trigger a sort on that column ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataGridColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is a control itself so you should be able to assign an handler to its [MouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event programatically.

Comment: yeah, I was aware of that but i thought there is a leaner way to do it because the left-button click is broad event for a special action as sorting